# How can I set attributes on <ul> tag that MvcConrib's MenuBuilder rendered?

Tags: c#, attributes, mvccontrib

I use this code the render the menu `<% Html.Menu(GridSampleMenu.AdminMenu(Url)); %>`
but I don't see any option to set the id on the rendered ul tag.

Are this is a known limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option out of the box to specify attributes on the elements that the Menu rendered, and I found this MenuBuilder very limited in this kind of functionality.

So, when I need this *heavy* attributes in any element, I just do it with regular typed HTML.